# Cómo utilizar DB:raw en un subquery de laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

estoy obteniendo datos de una tabla a través del siguiente código

```
    return Customer::select(DB::raw($formulaToGetNearestLocation))
        ->orderBy('distance')
        ->paginate(10);
```

**Distance es obtenido de mi formula, funciona muy bien hasta aquí**

la "formula" utilizada me obtiene distancias, algo totalmente útil que solo se obtiene con DB::raw,

el tema de esto es que el query final no debe ser así, en realidad esto debería ser un subquery, lo estoy intentando acomodar, hasta el momento tengo

```
    return Franchise::with('customers', function ($query) use ($formulaToGetNearestLocation){
        $query->select(DB::raw($formulaToGetNearestLocation))
            ->orderBy('distance');
    })->get();
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error cuando intento ejecutar el query

> TypeError mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string,
> Closure given

mi modelo `Franchise` tiene esta relación

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'franchise_customer', 'franchise_id', 'customer_id')
        ->using(FranchiseCustomer::class);
}
```

y mi modelo `Customer` tiene esta otra

```
public function franchises()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Franchise::class, 'franchise_customer', 'customer_id', 'franchise_id')
        ->using(FranchiseCustomer::class);
}
```

lo que yo quiero obtener es toda la lista de mi modelo `Franchise` (sin excepción ni filtros), ya sea teniendo O SIN TENER un customer, la lista de `Franchise` tiene relación con `Customer` de muchos a muchos (un customer puede tener varias franchises y la misma franchise pertenecer a varios customers)

Comment: muchas gracias, funcionó @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Franchise::with('customers', function ($query) use ($formulaToGetNearestLocation) {
    $query->select(DB::raw($formulaToGetNearestLocation))
        ->orderBy('distance');
})
->get();
```

El problema que tienes ahí es que le estás pasando una función como segundo argumento al método `with`

```
Franchise::with('customers', function ($query) {//...})
//                  ↑             ↑
//                primer       segundo
//               argumento    argumento
```

Y como está explicado en la documentación [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

Para cargar una relación con *eager load*, pero también especificar condiciones de consulta adicionales para la consulta *eager load*, puedes **pasarle una matriz de relaciones** al método `with` donde la clave de la matriz es un nombre de relación y el valor de la matriz es una función que agrega restricciones adicionales a la consulta de *eager load*.

Ejemplo:

```
with(['relacion' => function ($query) {...} ])
//   ↑ 
//   primer y único argumento
//   que es un array o matriz
```

O en tu código:

```
Franchise::with([
    'customers' => function ($query) use ($formulaToGetNearestLocation) {
        $query->select(DB::raw($formulaToGetNearestLocation))
            ->orderBy('distance');
    },
])
->get();
```